# Creating multipoint geometry in ArcMap using Python and ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, geometry, multipoint

I have specific points and I need to create multipoint geometries, in a ModelBuilder Python script, following an equation that provides me the new (x,y) points around my initial point.

Is there any way that you provide a function that produces Multipoints ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Online Help for [Multipoint (arcpy)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000000s000000) provides sample code to do this:

```
import arcpy

# A list of features and coordinate pairs
feature_info = [[[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 7]],
                [[6, 8], [5, 7], [7, 2], [9, 5]]]

# A list that will hold each of the Multipoint objects
features = []

for feature in feature_info:
    # Create a Multipoint object based on the array of points
    # Append to the list of Multipoint objects
    features.append(
        arcpy.Multipoint(
            arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature])))

# Persist a copy of the Multipoint objects using CopyFeatures
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, "c:/geometry/multipoints.shp")
```